# Scala Spark Uncaught DocumentDoesNotExistException while accessing Couchbase

Tags: scala, exception, apache-spark, couchbase

I'm writing a spark process in scala and trying to get a subdoc from couchbase from inside a mapPartitions function.

Using spark 2.1.0 and the spark connector to couchbase:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm also using this class for the access to couchbase: com.couchbase.spark.RDDFunctions

The code I'm having trouble with:

```
    val docsRDD = df
  .select(
    col(keyColumnName),
    concat(lit("devs."), $"udid").as(subdocColumnName))
  .filter(length(col(keyColumnName)) > 0)
  .distinct()
  .rdd
  .mapPartitions {
    valueIterator =>
      if (valueIterator.isEmpty) {
        Iterator[SubdocLookupResult]()
      } else {
        try {
          val specs = OnceIterable(valueIterator).toSeq.map(r => SubdocLookupSpec(r.getAs(keyColumnName).toString, Seq(r.getAs(subdocColumnName).toString), Seq()))

          new SubdocLookupAccessor(cbConfig, specs, EnvironmentUtils.bucketName)
            .compute()
        }
        catch {
          case _: Throwable => null
          case x => null
          case runtime: RuntimeException => null
          case cbExp: CouchbaseException => null
          case notExists: DocumentDoesNotExistException => null
          case e: Exception => null
        }
      }
  }
```

When running .compute(), if the document doesn't exist in CB, DocumentDoesNotExistException is thrown.

This is OK, of course, but I would like to catch that exception.

I've tried adding every possible general case in the catch section, and yet the exception is not caught the the run fails.

This is the error:

```
com.couchbase.client.java.error.DocumentDoesNotExistException: Document not found for subdoc API: pr_OcgltxCHeI0=
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.SubdocHelper.commonSubdocErrors(SubdocHelper.java:64)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.AsyncLookupInBuilder$5.call(AsyncLookupInBuilder.java:430)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.AsyncLookupInBuilder$5.call(AsyncLookupInBuilder.java:399)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:101)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65)
    at rx.internal.producers.ProducerArbiter.setProducer(ProducerArbiter.java:126)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.setProducer(OnSubscribeRedo.java:267)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:103)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.completeResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:376)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.access$000(AbstractGenericHandler.java:69)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:394)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.core.message.kv.subdoc.simple.SimpleSubdocResponse.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:109)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
    ... 21 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I catch this exception?

Comment: can you catch the exception this way outside of spark?

Comment: what do you mean "outside of spark"?